# show Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly.

Tags: codeigniter

show Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php while visiting my CI project

Answer (score 0):

The file mentioned in the message (index.php) is typically located in the root folder of your Codeigniter installation.

The normal files structure for Codeigniter is this.

```
/root_name (often named 'www' or 'htdocs')
     /application
     /system
     index.php <- Is the file to edit
```

The section of the index.php where you need to make the adjustment looks like this.

```
/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
$system_path = 'system';
```

If you use the normal installation folder structure then the correct entry is 'system'. If you have moved the 'system' folder to some other location, or renamed it, then the value of `$system_path` must be adjusted to match the new location or name.